# Would graphene be a good efficient conductor of electricity in mobile phones

Tags: conductivity, carbon-allotropes, semiconductors

Gold is commonly used in mobile phones as an electrical conductor,as it is apparently better than copper at conducting electricity
Quoting from extremetech.com :

"The materials recovered are reused in new electronics parts and the gold and other precious metals are melted down and sold as ingots to jewelers and investors as well as back to manufacturers who use gold in the circuit boards of mobile phones because gold conducts electricity even better than copper."

(Some of the information is irrelevant but i was to lazy to take it out)

But when I actually look at this table it says that gold is worse than copper at conducting electricity and has a higher resistivity rate

Please follow the link to see what I'm talking about
[Table of conductivity](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&rlz=1C1GGRV_enGB751GB751&sxsrf=ACYBGNTl7K47i1NakJgQMVwAsoOMlijqrw%3A1569516566834&ei=FuyMXbjMMseZ1fAPsZS3iA0&q=what%20is%20golds%20conductivity%20in%20siemens%20&oq=what%20is%20golds%20conductivity%20in%20siemens%20&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39.6580.6580..8524...0.2..0.82.82.1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.C25oLRyxmgE&ved=0ahUKEwi4r73r-O7kAhXHTBUIHTHKDdEQ4dUDCAs&uact=5)

So it's either that the information on the table is wrong or that the tech website was wrong (and it probably was)

Information found on investorintel.com

"Graphene is fantastically good at conducting electricity; its current density is 1,000,000 times greater than copper’s and its intrinsic mobility is 100 times greater than that of silicon. Electrons move through graphene with virtually no resistance and without mass. This means that graphene can carry electricity more efficiently, precisely and faster than any other material. It is anticipated that graphene will enable lithium batteries to have more than 10 times the electrical retention/capacity as anything presently in use."

But there are problems of it being to expensive to manufacture, but I do not understand why?

To clarify what I'm asking
1. Is gold better at conducting than copper
2. Is graphene better and more efficient at conducting energy (thermal and electrical) than any other known elements?

Comment: All kinds of materials, engineering, and manufacturing details are buried in such a comparison...

Comment: It's more like "too broad" though, if additional fluff won't get edited out.

Comment: If you trust the wikipedia (or whatever source it quotes) then copper is more conductive: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity#Resistivity_and_conductivity_of_various_materials